# Convert Facebook Fanpage ID to Fanpage Name PHP SDK

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

Well, I really have no idea how to do this, all I see in some posts here is like

use this and you will get fan page id thing.

```
$signedrequest = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
```

And so on..

But my problem lies in here, I'm trying to do a mysql select query, for example

```
//Note that $uid is MY user id 
$query = "SELECT fanpage_id FROM fb_table WHERE uid='".$uid."';
$result = mysql_query($query);
$fanpage_id = $result[0];
```

So if I echo the fan page id, it will output like this

```
420276361382765
```

How do I convert it to facebook fan page name using the PHP SDK?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are looking for pages liked by user_id? (Given user_id can only pull out the friend's liked pages). But it all depends whose token you are using to pull out the pages information.

Comment: No No No, just my user id. sorry for the vauge information.

Comment: Get all of the pages liked you?

Comment: Well that I'm trying to get is like if (420276361382765 == (some php sdk used function to get id) then echo the converted fan page name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Graph API:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/**user_id**/likes?fields=name,created_time,id,likes,talking_about_count&access_token=**Your_Access_Token**
```

This is through FQL:

```
select page_id from page_fan where uid = me()
```

You need to have the following permissions:

```
user_likes permissions if querying the current user.
friends_likes permissions if querying a user's friend.
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You Need **user_likes permissions**

'scope' => 'email,user_likes,friends_birthday',

```
$pages=$facebook->api("/me/likes");
             $row=array();
             foreach($pages['data'] as $row)
              {
                echo $row['category'] ;
                echo '<br>';
                echo $row['name'] ;
                echo '<br>';
                echo $row['id'] ;
                echo '<br>';
                echo $row['created_time'] ;
                echo '<br>--------------------------------------------------------------';
                echo'<br>';

              }
```

Hope it Helps