# Convert numeric fan page ID to String fan page id \ fan page name

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-page

This question is partially addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15043851/convert-facebook-fanpage-id-to-fanpage-name-php-sdk),
but I cannot use this answer, since my user doesn't necessarily like this specific fan page.

The issue:
I have numeric fan page IDs saved at my DB, I would like to provide my user with a link directly to my app page at a certain fan page.

The problem: `https://www.facebook.com/[NUMERIC_ID]/app_[MY_APP_ID]` Doesn't seem to work.
But `https://www.facebook.com/[FAN_PAGE_NAME]/app_[MY_APP_ID]` does work.

Thus I need a way to convert the numeric fan page id to the actual fan page name(maybe CURLing the page?).

I would like to do it either through the PHP SDK, the graph API, or FQL.
The language I need to implement this in is PHP.

EDIT:

I need a way of doing this with no auth token, or with the auth token of my app, since the mentioned page is a public page, that doesn't require Facebook authentication

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can find your answer here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

> To read a Page you need:
>
> - an app or user access token for public and non-demographically
>     restricted pages
> - a user access_token for restricted pages that the
>     current user is able to view (no special permissions required)

A Graph API request such as `/[PAGE_ID]?fields=id,name,link` will return (where PAGE_ID is 19292868552)

```
{
  "id": "19292868552", 
  "link": "http://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers", 
  "name": "Facebook Developers"
}
```

Comment: ( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught GraphMethodException: Unsupported get request. thrown in /var/www/dev/src/base_facebook.php on line 1255

Comment: http://graph.facebook.com/104413472438?fields=id,name,link
I think that for some pages you need the user token, and it is a problem, because I don't necessarily have it

Comment: Are you sure that page exists at all? Or perhaps has some restrictions? https://www.facebook.com/104413472438 - "Sorry, this page isn't available"

Comment: @OlegTikhonov Yes I am.

Comment: How can I prefer the same request providing my user token.

You are probably right,  perhaps there are some restrictions for that page.

I'll have to implement some logic, that tries to get /me, and subsequently /me/permissions and then the page, at the first catch it it tries to fetch the page data without the token, and in case it succeeds in getting /me and /me/permissions it send a request with a token and accordingly gives a link with the numeric fan page ID, or with the exact link to my app's page at this fan page

Comment: To get the tokens for the pages you manage you can do `[USER_ID]/accounts?manage_pages` https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#page_access_tokens

Comment: I'll try, thanks.
I don't manage those pages, they have a section of my app on the fan page navigation bar.
Do you know what I mean?

Comment: Any thoughts on this?